why does "show arp" on my Juniper EX3400 return empty?
JunOS version is 20.2R3.9.
For instance:
root@CLEANROOM-IDF-D8> show arp interface ge-0/0/4.0
{master:0}
root@CLEANROOM-IDF-D8>
...what gives? There is a device on that port and it's working, shouldn't I see a MAC address here?

If you're running the switch just for L2 there's no need for it to ARP and nothing in the ARP table.
I think what you're after is the MAC table - try show ethernet-switching table (thx @Jordan).

Actually you want "show ethernet-switching table" on an EX3400. "show interfaces mac-database" is PTX/MX.

Thanks, this is correct!
